# What pattern is this, and should I do it?

Tags: architecture, flash, actionscript-3, design-patterns

I'm making a game in as3 using flash develop and flash cs5. Everything is object oriented. I was wondering, should I have one "gateway" class that has a property-reference to all instantiations of other classes, and I just pass this gateway class to new objects, so they have access to every class. Like so:

```
 var block:Block = new Block(gateway);

 //In the block class:
 this.gateway.player.setHealth(100);
 //Or:
 this.gateway.input.lock();
```

Is this like a singleton pattern or something? Should I do this?

Answer (score 13):

This is called the [context object design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771983/what-is-context-object-design-pattern), and it is better than the singleton pattern.

- Context objects aid testing, because you can pass mock contexts to functions you want to test. Singletons hinder it, because to mock singletons you need to make them not singletons.
- Context objects makes your "global state" explicit, and therefore easier to reason about. If a function doesn't take a context object, you know it doesn't use any global context state. You have no such guarantee with singletons or global variables.
- Context objects are *very slightly* slower if you don't use them, because you add another parameter to all your function calls. They can be *faster* than globals if you do use them, and are nearly always faster than singletons.
- Context objects are easier to implement; usually they live on the heap or stack in a normal way. Singletons have tricky issues involving threading in many languages.

So no, this is not a singleton, it's way better than a singleton.

***However,*** you're still passing around a crapload of state - the fact you're keeping it all in a single local variable makes it more explicit, but still creates major [conflation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Keep in mind [the one responsibility rule](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneResponsibilityRule). It makes some sense for there to be a context that owns the player and the current level - they're related - but why does the same context own your keyboard input?

Consider different levels of contexts, for example:

- GameplayContext - owns the player, enemies, the level geometry, etc.
- InputContext - owns keyboard and mouse handles, input events, etc.
- GraphicsContext - owns textures, the window handle, etc.
- GlobalContext - owns a GameplayContext, a GraphicsContext, and an InputContext. This is where you want to apply the [service locator pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html), to be able to swap out some contexts for others as needed. And maybe, for quick iteration and testing, this should be in a real global variable - just realize that whenever you use it, [you're building up tech debt](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TechnicalDebt).

These contexts still conflate concerns somewhat - maybe some event handler takes a GameplayContext and really only needs the player - but the responsibilities are clearly laid out. You know that something that takes a GameplayContext won't load a texture; something taking an InputContext can't kill a player.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Some of the speed or threading concerns don't really apply in this context though (ActionScript3 doesn't support threading and a lot of speed improving mechanisms that work in C++ don't apply when using AS3).

Comment: I don't know much about the AS3VM, but in most dynamic languages, the cost of passing/receiving/using a local is still faster (array lookup) than the cost of looking up a global (hash lookup), and _much_ faster than calling a function (craploads of stuff) to get at it. So I think that advice still applies.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like the Singleton pattern. The way I understand it, you're passing an object with references to important game-objects to all of your instances.

If this would be the Singleton pattern, you would have:

```
AudioManager.getInstance().playSound(XY);
```

Whereas in your case you might have:

```
this.gateway.getAudioManager().playSound(XY);
```

It looks basically the same, but it really isn't. If you would want to replace `AudioManager` with a new (extended class) like `ExtendedAudioManager`, you would hit a wall using the Singleton pattern. Your gateway approach will handle that just fine though.

The drawback of your approach is that you'll have to pass around the `gateway` everywhere. 
The [service locator pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html) (proposed by Joe Wreschnig in [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/alternatives-to-singletons-globals) thread), looks like a good replacement for your "gateway pattern".

Sometimes it's better to just run with the simple and straightforward method instead of over-designing things though. Especially when it's a small project or a prototype.
Maybe you could make that `gateway` some sort of a global variable.. eg. `Game.gateway` and run with it.

Answer (score -2):

Most solutions to this problem, including the Singleton pattern, involve the use of static variables.  If you'll only ever have one player, you can just have Player be a singleton class, which means you could access the Player instance through something like Player.currentPlayer.  Many people rage against Singletons, however.  You could also have a ResourceManager or similar class that contains static references to various useful global or pretty-darn-global variables.  In your code, you might as well make "Gateway's" variables statically accessible instead of inflating your code by passing it around everywhere.

Comment: The question has changed substantially since I made this answer, enough that it doesn't seem worth it to edit it.

Comment: Apart from the title, nothing changed in the question.

Comment: What? Nothing has changed other than the title. -1

Comment: I think I was thinking of the title here;  I remember the original title being something like "How should I do this?"  It's totally possible that I misread the initial title/question when I made the answer.